# system.out.println doesn't conforms to system.out.print

Tags: java, println

`system.out.println` doesn't conforms to `system.out.print` when printing a `java.util.stream`.

```
1)
Stream.of(1, "1B").forEach(System.out::print);
result:
11B

2)
Stream.of(1, "1C").forEach(System.out::println);
result
1
1C

3)
Stream.of(1, "1B").forEach(System.out::println);
result
1
```

Can anybody explain why `1B` is excluded from the result in case `3`? I suppose `"1B"` conflicts with binary literals. If **yes**, why is the case `1` printing `"1B"` with the print method? I also wonder why `"1B"` is not considered being a string literal in the stream in case `3`?

Comment: I'd guess it's just that the standard output hasn't been flushed for some reason.

Comment: Stream.of(1, "1B").forEach(System.out::println); worked as expected for me in junit eclipse test...

Comment: [Works as expected](http://ideone.com/98yHpp)...

Comment: You are doing something else wrong because you shouldn't expect there to be a difference and indeed there isn't http://ideone.com/9rqiu6